# How to make a list column and its items read only in datasheet view?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, datasheet

Is it possible to make a list items read only in datasheet view? Need the steps on making the datasheet view to be read only for a list. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need To edit " AllItems.aspx " page and add Content editor web-Part and add some jQuery code to disable the grid.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/98543436-4b53-4765-a7d9-6983c4b30ea7/how-make-data-sheet-view-read-only-?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

Comment: can u provide the jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Simple "Non Code" way would be to create Lookup columns back to your list and use the lookup columns in your view.